# Solving a system of matrix equations in Mathematica

Tags: math, matrix, optimization, wolfram-mathematica, approximation

I am trying to find a matrix that satisfies six matrix equations.

The equations are as follows:

(Conjugate[ConjugateTranspose[B1]].X.ConjugateTranspose[B1]) == TotalPrB1,
(Conjugate[ConjugateTranspose[B2]].X.ConjugateTranspose[B2]) == TotalPrB2, (Conjugate[ConjugateTranspose[B3]].X.ConjugateTranspose[B3]) == TotalPrB3, (Conjugate[ConjugateTranspose[B4]].X.ConjugateTranspose[B4]) == TotalPrB4, (Conjugate[ConjugateTranspose[B5]].X.ConjugateTranspose[B5]) == TotalPrB5, (Conjugate[ConjugateTranspose[B6]].X.ConjugateTranspose[B6]) == TotalPrB6

Where, every matix is 8*8. I want to find a X that satisfies all the above equations.

I tried to use FindRoot and Nsolve function but was unable to get the desired result. FindRoot can only solve for X satisfying one matrix equation.

Can you suggest a way to find X solving the above system?

Comment: Better to ask Mathematica questions on the [Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/) stack exchange site.

Comment: I think first you'll need to study whether there exists a solution; for that, see math.stackexchange.com. What I see is that if the B matrices are invertible, then each equation has a unique solution, and then the set of 6 equations has a solution only if all 6 solutions happen to be the same -- you can verify that by solving one by one and then comparing. If the B matrices are not invertible, then for each one X falls in some subspace of R^8 of dimension >= 1, and the question is then whether those subspaces intersect. In this case, too, you can solve one by one and look at the solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a fraction of a second this

```
B1=RandomReal[{-1,1},{8,8}];B2=RandomReal[{-1,1},{8,8}];B3=RandomReal[{-1,1},{8,8}];
B4=RandomReal[{-1,1},{8,8}];B5=RandomReal[{-1,1},{8,8}];B6=RandomReal[{-1,1},{8,8}];
X=Array[x,{8,8}];
{TotalPrB1,TotalPrB2,TotalPrB3,TotalPrB4,TotalPrB5,TotalPrB6}=RandomReal[{-10,10},6];
Reduce[{
  Conjugate[ConjugateTranspose[B1]].X.ConjugateTranspose[B1]==TotalPrB1,
  Conjugate[ConjugateTranspose[B2]].X.ConjugateTranspose[B2]==TotalPrB2,
  Conjugate[ConjugateTranspose[B3]].X.ConjugateTranspose[B3]==TotalPrB3,
  Conjugate[ConjugateTranspose[B4]].X.ConjugateTranspose[B4]==TotalPrB4,
  Conjugate[ConjugateTranspose[B5]].X.ConjugateTranspose[B5]==TotalPrB5,
  Conjugate[ConjugateTranspose[B6]].X.ConjugateTranspose[B6]==TotalPrB6},
  Flatten[X]]
```

returns False, indicating that there is no solution for those particular coefficients. If I fake my matricies to ensure there is a solution then it finds it in the same fraction of a second. Based on experience, with this many variables you are VERY lucky that it is able to find any solution at all, I suspect that is only because the form of your problem is simple. BUT I have no idea what your six matricies and six coefficients are, yours probably aren't Real, and whether a solution exists for those nor not.

So what happens when you use this code with your coefficients?

Comment: Hi Bill! Thanks for the code. I didn't know about the Reduce function. Can you suggest how to save the solution of this Reduce to a matrix; to further compare it with another matrix?

Comment: Since I cannot see any of your matricies or coefficients, I cannot be certain that this will be the correct form and so I have to guess. Try wrapping `sol=X/.ToRules[...]` around that `Reduce[...]` and see if that gives you the solution in the form that you desire.